# How to repeat one demo variable for one participant with multiple measures in r?

Tags: r

I have two datasets. One dataset names "demo", another dataset names "analysis". I want to copy one variable names"beeptime" from demo to analysis.

Here is how the demo looks:

[image]

Here is how the analysis looks:

[image]

I want to use code:

```
analysis = analysis %>% mutate(ethnic = case_when(analysis$subjno %in% demo$subjno ~ demo$beeptime))
```

But it reports an error:

> must be length 5410 or one, not 193.

I think the problem is in analysis, the participant has multiple measures. (in the demo, one participant has one line, but in analysis, one participant with multiple lines). I do not how to solve this.

Comment: Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Sounds like you need to `join_xxxx` your tables rather than simply `mutate` `analysis`...

Comment: left_join(demo, analysis, by = "subjno")

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will not upload images next time.

Comment: the left_join is a good idea, but I already try it, and it fails in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to run the code below? You have to different solutions, to keep all multiple lines for each subject (test1), or to keep only one for each of them. If this is not your desired result, you will have to be more specific.

```
library(dplyr)
demo <- data.frame(subjno = c(235 , 5851, 5852),
                   beptime = c(920.125, 1049.92, 936.35))

analysis <- data.frame(subjno = c(235, 235, 5851, 5851,5852))

test1 <- left_join(demo, analysis, by = "subjno")
test2 <- left_join(demo, analysis, by = "subjno") %>% distinct()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. It partly solved my problem. Thank you. 
May I ask that, do you know how to improve your code? The "demo" dataset has 30 columns, and the "analysis" data has 40 columns, after using left_join, the new combined dataset has 69 columns in total. I think it is trouble to manually delete a lot of columns. Actually, I just want copy one column (beptime) from demo to analysis.

I think there are two ways to improve:
(1) use left_join, but only select and join one specific variable/column
(2) After join, use code to delete the repeated columns/variables

Comment: test2 <- left_join(demo %>% select(subjno, beptime), analysis, by = "subjno") %>% distinct()